# Sharepoint 2016 On Premise Global navigation

Tags: custom-masterpage, global-navigation, top-navigation

I want to use the navigation options through site settings to create the top nav on my site.  But it seems that the master page using some sort of custom usercontrol (ascx) or custom web parts to set the navigation but I am not the original person who set up the site collection and all of the sites underneath.

I am also not familiar with using anything to set up navigation outside of structural or managed navigation.  So I am trying to remove the custom control and set up the navigation the way that I am familiar with.  I know this is a vague question but hoping for some help to steer me in the right direction.

Here is the code from the master page if that helps:

```
<%@Page language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingLayoutPage, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" %>

<%@Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>

<%@Register TagPrefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>

<%@Register TagPrefix="Publishing" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>

<%@Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead">

<Publishing:EditModePanel runat="server" id="editmodestyles">
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/editmode15.css %&gt;" After="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/~language/Themable/Core Styles/pagelayouts15.css %&gt;" runat="server"></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
</Publishing:EditModePanel>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"></SharePoint:ProjectProperty>
    <PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server"></PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea">
    <PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">
    </PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>
 </asp:Content>
        
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain">
<style type="text/css">
#s4-workspace { overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden !important; }
#navigation { padding-left: 2%; }
ul#navigation > li:first-child  {display: none; }
#contentBox { margin-right: 0 !important; margin-left: 0 !important;}
#contentWrapper.col-sm-12 { padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; }
#acps-content { padding: 0 1%; }
#acps-content .col-sm-4 { border-left: 0 !important; width: 33.3333333%; }
#acps-content .col-sm-4 .row-WPZone { border-left: 0 !important; }
#collection-header {display: none; }
#sideNavBox { display: none; }
#topbreadcrumb { display: none !important; }
#subtitle { display: none !important; }
#mainbody { max-width: 100% !important; margin: 0 !important;  /*background-color: #c7d3db; */ }
.row { background-color: transparent; }
#mainbody.col-md-9, #full-width-top { width: 100%; }
#full-width-top.row { margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; }
#pdf-help { max-width: 1500px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 auto !important; }
#bottom-content { padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%; }
#acps-content.row:after {content: ; }
#bottom-content.row:before {content: ; }
#bottom-content.row:after {content: ; }
.carousel-inner { max-height: 450px;}
.carousel-inner img { width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;}
.carousel-control:hover, .carousel-control a:hover { text-decoration: none !important;}
#acps-content { max-width: 1500px; margin: 0 auto; padding-top: 0; background-color: #fff;}
.nav { margin-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0;}
.ms-WPHeader td { border-bottom: 1px solid #5195ba;}
tr.ms-viewheadertr { display: none;}
#ctl00_m_g_6d7c734c_f493_4503_a9b3_f7be1fd5122f br { display: none;}
#MSOZoneCell_WebPartctl00_m_g_a51ae5fd_5b55_4c78_8e9d_147d6a9b7804 > table.s4-wpTopTable { position: relative; top: 2em;}
.tab-content { padding: 0 0.5em;}
#newsTabs { margin-top: 0; }
#newsTabs.nav > li > a { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.9rem; color: #0072bc; padding: 4px 6px; }
#newsTabs.nav > .active > a { color: #924b84;}
.nav-tabs { border-bottom: 1px solid #5195ba;}
.nav-tabs > .active > a, .nav-tabs > .active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > .active > a:focus { border: 1px solid #5195ba; border-bottom-color: transparent;}
#sptlt { padding: 0;  height: 750px; overflow: auto;}
.spotlight-item { padding-bottom: 0.8em; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;}
.spotlight-item h4 { font-size: 10pt !important;  margin-left: 0 !important; margin-top: 0.5em !important; }
.spotlight-item h4 a:link { text-decoration: none !important; }
.spotlight-item p { margin-left: 0 !important; }
.spotlight-item img { max-width: 40%; margin: 0 8px 8px 8px; float: right; }
.s4-title {  display: none;}
.flex-viewport { max-height: 200px;}
h2, .row-WPZone h2, .row-WPZone h2 a, .row-WPZone h2 a:hover { margin: 0 !important; }
#twitter-widget-0 {  width: 100% !important;}
.twitter-timeline-rendered {  width: 100% !important; }
/** New Calendar Widget **/
.ecl-calendar{    border-color: #036; }
.ecl-calendar table,.ecl-calendar tr:first-child{ background-color: #b1daf5; font-weight: bold;}
.ecl-day:hover, .ecl-event:hover,.ecl-today:hover,.ecl-weekend:hover,.ecl-other-month:hover{    background-color: #efd4d4;}
.ecl-today{ background-color: #d3e6f4;}
.ecl-listing h3 { text-decoration: none; color: #369 !important; font-size: 10pt;}
.ecl-listing li { margin-left: 0.1em;}

#pdf-help { text-align: center;    padding: 1em 0;    margin: 0 auto;    border-top: 0;    background-color: #fff;    max-width: 1500px;}

@media (max-width: 979px) { 
#mainbody > #contentBox { margin-left: 0 !important; min-width: 0; }
#newsTabs.nav > li > a { padding: 5px !important; }
.nav-tabs > li > a { font-size: 10pt; }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) { 
.navbar-toggle { margin-right: 30px !important; }
#mainbody.col-md-9 { padding-left: 0 !important; padding-right: 0 !important; }
#mainbody > #contentBox { margin-left: 0 !important; }
#acps-content .col-sm-4 { width: 100%; }
</style>
<!-- First Row (full width carousel) -->

<div class="row" id="full-width-top">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row-WPZone">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow1Column1" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end 1st Row l. 90 -->

<!-- Second Row (Three columns) -->
<div class="row" id="acps-content">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row-WPZone">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="newsTabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#sptlt" id="spotlight">Spotlight</a></li>
<li><a href="#pr">Press Releases</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="sptlt">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow2Column1" title="Tab1-View" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="pr">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow2Column1b" title="Tab2-View" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div><!-- end tab-content -->

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#newsTabs a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})

</script>

</div><!-- end row-WPZone -->
</div><!-- end col-sm-4, 1st Column, l. 96 -->

<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="row-WPZone">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow2Column2Sub1" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 last-col">
<div class="row-WPZone">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow2Column2Sub2" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div>

</div><!-- end 2nd Row, acps-content, 3x col-sm-4 l. 99 -->


<!-- Third Row (Two columns) -->

<div id="bottom-content" class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="row-WPZone">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow3Column1" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6">
<div class="row-WPZone">
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" AllowPersonalization="false" ID="bootstrapRow3Column2" FrameType="None" Orientation="Vertical"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- end 3rd Row, bottom-content, 2 x col-sm-6, l. 144 -->


<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery("#SkiptoContent").replaceWith("<a href='#spotlight' id='SkiptoContent' class='ms-accessible ms-acc-button' onClick='javascript:window.document.getElementById('spotlight').focus();return false;'>Skip to Main Content</a>");
});
</script>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the `Term Store Manager` located here:
[https://yourtenant.com/sites/[SiteCollection]/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx](https://yourtenant.com/sites/%5BSiteCollection%5D/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx)

**Guide to TSM**: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-of-term-store-management-in-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365/

Comment: Yes - thank you.  I have set up a basic global nav using that method on another template and it seems to be working.  What I am trying to do is find the control or place in my master page that removes the custom global nav so I can put my own nav in place.  I just don't know where to look to remove / turn that off.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. You can find it in Site Settings - Navigation, and choose where you want to show the navigation from.